# Question about python construction

Tags: python, compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter

A friend of mine that is a programmer told me that "Python is written in Python" or something like that. He meant that Python interpreter is written in Python (I think). I've read in some websites that Python interpret in real time ANY programming language (even C++ and ASM). Is this true?

Could someone explain me HOW COULD IT BE?

The unique explanation that I came up with after thinking a bit is: python is at the same "level" of ASM, it makes sense to python interpret any language (that is in a higher level), am I right? Does this make sense?

I would be grateful is someone explain me a little about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It's not true. The standard implementation of Python - CPython - is written in C, although much of the standard library is written in Python. There are other implementations in Java (Jython) and .NET (IronPython).

There is a project called PyPy which, among other things, is rewriting the C parts of Python into Python. But the main development of Python is still based on C.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'll add that "Python" means both the interpreter and the standard library. The CPython interpreter is written in C, but large parts of the standard library are in Python.

Comment: While true, it might be helpful to rearrange this answer to explain how pypy can exist.  I think the focus of the question is on the apparent circularity.  A sentence on how pypy breaks the circle might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend told you that Python is [self-hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hosting):

> The term self-hosting was coined to refer to the use of a computer program as part of the toolchain or operating system that produces new versions of that same program—for example, a compiler that can compile its own source code. Self-hosting software is commonplace on personal computers and larger systems. Other programs that are typically self-hosting include kernels, assemblers, shells and revision control software.

Of course, the very first revision of Python had to be bootstrapped by some other mechanism -- perhaps C or C++ as these are fairly standard targets for [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler).

Comment: The "very first revision" had to be bootstrapped?  You're implying that subsequent revisions did not... i.e. that Python self-hosts.  It does not (with CPython anyway... PyPy changes the picture).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when someone says language X is written in X, they mean that first a compiler or interpreter for X was written in assembly or other such language, compiled, and then a *better* compiler or interpreter was written in X.

Additionally, once a very basic compiler/interpreter for X exists, it is sometimes easier to add new language features, classes, etc. to X by writing them in X than to extend the compiler/interpreter itself.

Comment: So it can be made with any language? I mean, rewrite a better compiler of language X in X?

Comment: @Rafael: Theoretically, yes, although some languages are better suited for that type of development than others.  It also depends a lot on what is meant by 'better'.

Answer (score 0):

Python is written in C ([CPython](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CPython)) as well as Python.

Read about [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) -- that's Python written in Python.

Writing Python in Python is a two-step dance.

1. Write Python in some other language.  C, Java, assembler, COBOL, whatever.
2. Once you have a working implementation of Python (i.e., passes all the tests) you can then write Python in Python.

When you read about pypy, you'll see that they do something a hair more sophisticated than this.  "We are using a subset of the high-level language Python, called RPython, in which we write languages as simple interpreters with few references to and dependencies on lower level details."

So they started with a working Python and then broke the run-time into this RPython kernel which is the smallest nugget of Python  goodness.  Then they built the rest of Python around the RPython kernel.